# reading big-endian files in little-endian system

Tags: c, endianness

I have a data file that I need to read in C. It is compirsed of alternating 16-bit integer stored in binary form, and I need only the first column (ie, every other entry starting at 0)

I have a simple python script that reads the files accurately:

```
import numpy as np


fname = '[filename]'
columntypes = np.dtype([('curr_pA', '>i2'),('volts', '>i2')])
test = np.memmap(fname, dtype=columntypes,mode='r')['curr_pA']
```

I want to port this to C. Because my machine is natively little-endian I need to manually perform the byte swap. Here's what I have done:

```
void swapByteOrder_int16(double *current, int16_t *rawsignal, int64_t length)
{
    int64_t i;
    for (i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        current[i] = ((rawsignal[2*i] << 8) | ((rawsignal[2*i] >> 8) & 0xFF));
    }
}


int64_t read_current_int16(FILE *input, double *current, int16_t *rawsignal, int64_t position, int64_t length)
{
    int64_t test;

    int64_t read = 0;

    if (fseeko64(input,(off64_t) position*2*sizeof(int16_t),SEEK_SET))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    test = fread(rawsignal, sizeof(int16_t), 2*length, input);
    read = test/2;
    if (test != 2*length)
    {
        perror("End of file reached");
    }
    swapByteOrder_int16(current, rawsignal, length);
    return read;
}
```

In the `read_current_int16` function I use `fread` to read a large chunk of data (both columns) into `rawsignal` array. I then call `swapByteOrder_int16` to pick off every other value, and swap its bytes around. I then cast the result to `double` and store it in `current`.

It doesn't work. I get garbage as the output in the C code. I think I've been starting at it for too long and can no longer see my own errors. Can anyone spot anything glaringly wrong?

Comment: Why does code use `double` in `swapByteOrder_int16(double *current, int16_t *rawsignal, int64_t length)` instead of `int16_t`?

Comment: The rest of the code uses `double` to process the output of the I/O section of the code. Since I'm casting from `int16_t` to `double` there should be no loss of precision. There is an implicit cast in the assignment to `current[i]`.

Comment: `rawsignal[2*i]` means that the input is 32 bits per int. Now, if those are also swapped, you should use `rawsignal[2*(i+1)-1]` Use a debugger to check what is happening.

Comment: `rawsignal` should be unsigned. Otherwise the `>> 8` may move in 1-bits (sign extension).

Comment: You may not need to port this to C.  See [Byte-swapping Introduction to byte ordering and ndarrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.byteswapping.html) from the `numpy` docs.

Comment: OK, so code used `double` later on, then why call the function `swapByteOrder_int16()` as doing some `double` math in it mis-leads.

Comment: @Paul Ogilvie I don't quite understand. `rawsignal[2*i]` just refers to the 2i-th `16-bit `int` int he array, no? I will change to an unsigned array for rawsignal.

Comment: Perhaps `((rawsignal[2*i] << 8) | ((rawsignal[2*i] >> 8) & 0xFF))` --> `((rawsignal[i] << 8) | ((rawsignal[i] >> 8) & 0xFF))`  Why the *2`?

Comment: @chux, no, because then I will get alternating values from each column. the data is stored as [good value][bad value][good value][badvalue]. I need to pick out the good values and discard the bad ones.

Comment: I see the "pick off every other value" now.

Comment: `hton[s|l]` and `ntoh[s|l]` are useful library functions/macros to reverse byte order.

Comment: @tofro `ntoh[s|l]` and company do not necessarily reverse the byte order.  Then adjust the byte order from local (LE, BE, etc.) to network endian (BE) which may be a no-op.  What we know here is the C code and the file data are opposites.

Comment: Big Endian is also called network order. You can use ntoh() for 16 bits, ntohl() for 32. https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Byte-Order.html
Those functions are also available on Windows. If you're using the GNU compiler, it might be even better to use the intrinsic functions `__builtin_bswap16` `__builtin_bswap32` `__builtin_bswap64` because they only generate one instruction for the whole conversion.

Comment: @chux But in this case, the raw data is effectively in "network byte order" (i.e. big-endian), so `ntohs` should effectively do the right thing, but the result will still need converting casting to `int16_t` before converting to `double`. (I know that conversion to `int16_t` is non-portable, but it's easy!)

Comment: @Ian True, OP did say "Because my machine is natively little-endian" thus implying `BE` in the file.

Comment: Thanks for the help, all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform the endian swap as unsigned math and then assign to `double`.

```
void swapByteOrder_int16(double *current, const int16_t *rawsignal, size_t length) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      int16_t x = rawsignal[2*i];
      x = (x*1u << 8) | (x*1u >> 8);
      current[i] = x;
    }
}
```

Comment: This does the trick. I figured it out slightly differently, but I think our approaches are equivalent.

Comment: See my posted answer for the way I implemented it, but this post gave me the answer so I accepted it.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this mask and shift combination:

```
current[i] = ((rawsignal[2*i] & 0x00ff) << 8) | (rawsignal[2*i] >> 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by several people, doing the shifts as unsigned does the trick. I am answering this with my implementation just for the sake of completeness since I tweaked it a little from the accepted answer:

```
void swapByteOrder_int16(double *current, uint16_t *rawsignal, int64_t length)
{
    union int16bits bitval;

    int64_t i;
    for (i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        bitval.bits = rawsignal[2*i];
        bitval.bits = (bitval.bits << 8) | (bitval.bits >> 8);
        current[i] = (double) bitval.currentval;
    }
}

union int16bits
{
    uint16_t bits;
    int16_t currentval;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Swapping bits with unsigned types will make things much easier:

```
void swapByteOrder_int16(double *current, void const *rawsignal_, size_t length)
{
    uint16_t const *rawsignal = rawsignal_;
    size_t i;
    for (i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
       uint16_t tmp = rawsignal[2*i];
       tmp = ((tmp >> 8) & 0xffu) | ((tmp << 8) & 0xff00u);
       current[i] = (int16_t)(tmp);
    }
}
```

NOTE: when `rawsignal` is not aligned, you have to `memcpy()` it.

Comment: I believe this is equivalent to the answer I accepted, but you were slightly slower ^_^. For interest, I posted my solution as implemented as another answer.

Comment: The first `& 0xffu` is not needed.  The second `& 0xffu` is wrong, perhaps 0xFF00 (and also not needed).

Comment: Please fix the masking since it is not correct - this code won't work.

Comment: chux: yes, the first `&` is not needed.  But it makes things more symmetrically (e.g. when converting an `uint32_t`).  It increases readability too and almost every compiler will optimize it away.